# Как принять pull request частично?

Tags: git, github

Есть два форка, свой и чужой. Во втором в начале несколько нужных мне коммитов, а далее ненужные. Как смержить к себе только первые n коммитов из другого форка?

Comment: Либо вы не вполне понимаете, что такое pull request, либо вы описали немного не то, что на самом деле хотите сделать .-.

Comment: @D-side, может быть, объясните что не так

Comment: Pull request это просьба принять изменения. А то, что описываете вы, больше похоже на частичное **принятие** pull request (если этот request вообще был).

Comment: @D-side да, требуется именно частичное принятие, реквест можно самому себе делать с чужим форком, но там нет выбора коммита, на сколько я заметил, запрос делается на HEAD указанной ветки указанного форка. Попробую ваш ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала, следует получить PR к себе в локальный репозиторий. Если этого не произошло автоматически, это можно сделать [по рецепту в справке Гитхаба](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/):

```
git fetch origin pull/{ID}/head
```

Также можно получить чужую ветку локально полностью, для работы с ней:

```
git fetch origin pull/{ID}/head:{local-branch}
```

Потом можно делать как вам сказал ixSci:

```
git merge {commit-SHA}
git push
```

Не забудьте также закрыть PR в веб-интерфейсе, чтобы больше не висел.

Answer (score 5):

Всё просто, находите commit SHA, который Вас интересует, и, находясь в нужной Вам ветке, делает:

```
git merge <commit-SHA>
```

Это команда вольёт все изменения, которые произошли с тех пор, как Ваша и чужая ветка разошлись, вплоть до нужной фиксации(commit), SHA-идентификатор которой Вы указали.

Comment: хм, но ведь этот коммит, до которого я хочу сделать мердж, находится в другом форке в  ветке с таким же именем.

Comment: @sercxjo Это совершенно не проблема. Вы мой ответ читали?

Comment: @sercxjo, имя ветки в git это условность, оно не имеет никакого значения.

Answer (score 3):

Если коммитов мало, то проще всего скачать их в локальный репозиторий для свободы действий:

```
git remote add форк URL_форка
git fetch форк
```

...а далее могу предложить два варианта:

- ### Простой

  Найти нужные SHA-хэши нужных коммитов в журнале ветки:

  ```
  git log форк/ветка
  ```

  `cherry-pick` по хэшам/SHA в порядке их применения:

  ```
  git checkout локальная_ветка
  git cherry-pick a1a1a1 b2b2b2 c3c3c3
  #               ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^ ^^^^^^ префиксы хэшей коммитов
  ```

  Ошибиться тут особо негде, но если вы нервничаете, можете предварительно сделать так:

  ```
  git checkout -b ненужная_ветка локальная_ветка
  ```

  ...и `cherry-pick`'айте в неё. Когда в ней будет то, что вам (на вид) надо, смерджите её в основную, затребовав "перемотку" (лишняя страховка от нежелательных эффектов):

  ```
  git checkout локальная_ветка
  git merge --ff-only ненужная_ветка
  ```
- ### Сложный *(но может быть удобнее)*

  *Interactive rebase* (`rebase -i`), хорош когда значительная часть их истории общая, и различия легко разгрести:

  ```
  # сделать на ветке с нужными изменениями новую ветку
  git checkout -b новые_изменения форк/ветка
  # вычислить отсутствующие коммиты и перенести ветку на верхушку локальная_ветка
  git rebase -i локальная_ветка новые_изменения
  ```

  Это выведет текстовый редактор со списком коммитов, которые есть в `новые_изменения`, но в `локальная_ветка` отсутствуют. Каждая строчка это один коммит: операция (там написано что делает каждая из них, по умолчанию `pick` то же что и `cherry-pick`), хэш и описание. После того, как вы закроете редактор, означенный участок ветки `новые_изменения` будет **переписан** согласно тому, что вы напишете в редакторе.

  Убрав соответствующую строчку, вы уберёте коммит (из `новые_изменения`, но не из исходной `форк/ветка`). А другие операции вас на данный момент не интересуют.

  Переписывание истории это опасное дело, поэтому делается в новой ненужной ветке, которую можно грохнуть, если что-то пойдёт не так. И по окончании процедуры у вас должна получиться ветка, которая ответвляется от верхушки вашей `локальная_ветка` и поверх неё содержит **только** нужные вам изменения из форка. Можно делать мердж с `--ff-only` (см. выше).

**Вообще говоря**, делают они примерно одно и то же. Interactive rebase избавляет только от ручного копания в логе.

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл следующее решение.

1. Подготовил ветку `import` от общего между форками коммита.
   и записал изменения на сервер:

   ```
   git branch import 0cc8d855adb457d1860d6e25cb93b6cc75d5a09d
   git push --all
   ```
2. На сайте создал pull request с интересующим форком в новую ветку и принял его.
3. Скачал изменения новой ветки, нашёл интересующие коммиты:

   ```
   git checkout import
   git pull origin import
   git log
   ```
4. Выполнил слияние до нужного коммита. Тут возможны коллизии, но у меня всё прошло гладко.

   ```
   git checkout master
   git merge a9219aa49e31bd38a6e00b0c0b17428f3fe67229
   ```
5. Записал изменения на сервер.

   ```
   git push
   ```

Частичный pull request в чужой форк, можно делать также через создание дополнительной ветки в своём форке.

Comment: Слишком сложно. Достаточно было последних трех команд.